# Difference between angular.fromJson and $scope.$eval when applied to JSON string

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

In my angularjs apps, I usually parse a JSON string by using `angular.fromJson`, like so:

```
var myObject=angular.fromJSON(jsonString);
```

However, it seems that I would obtain the same result by using `$scope.$eval`:

```
var myObject=$scope.$eval(jsonString);
```

[See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hL34da8h/)

Or by using vanilla javaScript, like so:

```
var myObject=JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

- Is there any particular reason to use `angular.fromJSON` rather than `JSON.parse`?
- Is there any possible issue when using `$scope.$eval` to parse a JSON string?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Check out the [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/Angular.js#L1211):

```
function fromJson(json) {
  return isString(json)
      ? JSON.parse(json)
      : json;
}
```

They're just passing through to `JSON.parse`.

As for [$eval](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/rootScope.js#L938) it shells out to [$parse](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/parse.js#L1647):

```
  // $scope.$eval source:
  $eval: function(expr, locals) {
    return $parse(expr)(this, locals);
  },
```

$parse source is too long to post, but it is essentially capable of converting inline (stringified) objects to *real* Objects and so it makes sense that in this case, it will actually convert your JSON as well.

(I did not know this until reading through the $parse source just now.)

> Is there any particular reason to use angular.fromJSON rather than JSON.parse?

Nope, not really. Although they do check to you to ensure that you don't double-parse a JSON string, like so:

```
var jsonString = '{"foo":"bar"}';
var json = JSON.parse(jsonString); // Parsing once is good :)
JSON.parse(json); // Parsing twice is bad :(
```

> Is there any possible issue when using $scope.$eval to parse a JSON string?

I don't think so off the top of my head, other than that you're doing more work than is necessary. So if you know you have JSON, there's no reason to use the heavier $parse function.

Comment: Yet there are some (slight) differences in performance http://jsperf.com/json-parse-v-angular-fromjson

Comment: `$scope.$eval` is for evaluating JavaScript expressions. If you try to eval JSON you'll get an error.

Comment: It seems to eval json and return an object: please check the fiddle I provided

Comment: @brianvaughn, thank you for taking an interest in this post. You are showing effort, and I would like to accept your answer :) however, you have not really answered yet the questions at the end at the post, which  are: Is there any particular reason to use angular.fromJSON rather than JSON.parse? Is there any possible issue when using $scope.$eval to parse a JSON string?

Comment: Sorry, I thought that answer was implicit. I'll update my response once more. ;)

Answer (score 5):

The above answer is almost correct. However, there *is* a potential issue with using `$scope.$eval()` to parse a JSON string, which does not exist with either `JSON.parse()` or `angular.fromJson()`: security. Angular allows an expression to contain complex JavaScript including function calls, conditionals with `?:`, variable assignments, and so on. All of these are recognised and processed if you use `$scope.$eval()`, even if they were added by a malicious end-user.

JSON does not support any of those more complex JavaScript features, nor anything else potentially "dangerous". If you use a true JSON parser like `JSON.parse()` or `angular.fromJson()`, there is no chance of malicious code being injected and executed.

Since Angular expressions are isolated and evaluate only in the current `$scope`, the risk of code injection is somewhat mitigated - `$scope.$eval()` is far less dangerous than JavaScript's native `eval()` for parsing JSON. However there is still no reason to use either function for this purpose, since there is a potential security risk *and* using a proper JSON parser is likely to be faster.