# What is difference between angular.fromJson and JSON.parse?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

Is there any major difference between angular.fromJson and JSON.parse ? so that we would need to use angular.fromJson .

Comment: Similar content. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29243854/difference-between-angular-fromjson-and-scope-eval-when-applied-to-json-string

Answer (score 15):

The difference is that `angular.fromJson` parses and returns input data only in case its type is a `string`. Otherwise is returns input.

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/Angular.js#L1323-L1339

```
/**
 * @ngdoc function
 * @name angular.fromJson
 * @module ng
 * @kind function
 *
 * @description
 * Deserializes a JSON string.
 *
 * @param {string} json JSON string to deserialize.
 * @returns {Object|Array|string|number} Deserialized JSON string.
 */
function fromJson(json) {
  return isString(json)
      ? JSON.parse(json)
      : json;
}
```