# Angular Js beginner Ajax Call

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax

I'm new to angular js, Inside my controller.js are controllers for my app, which is 100% working.  What I'm having problem is how to make an ajax call using angular js. I'm trying to fetch data from my service and pass it to my index.html using this ajax.  When I try to debug the code, it only hits on `$http` but doesn't go through the code inside it. What am I doing wrong here?

```
$http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://someService.site.net/site.aspx',
        data:{action:'someAction', position:'founders'},
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    }).then(function successCallback(response){

        var json =jQuery.parseJSON(response);
        var htmldata="";
        for(i=0; i<json.length; i++)
        {
            var htmlInfo = '<li><div class=\'col\'><a href="'+ json[i].Id +'"><img width=\'100%\' height=\'auto\' src="'+json[i].Image + '" class=\'profile-img\' /><h3>' +json[i].Name+'</h3><p>'+json[i].Title+'</p></a></div></li>';

            htmldata+= htmlInfo;
        }
        jQuery("#vflist").html(htmldata);
    }, function errorCallback(response){

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Mark your breakpoints on success and error callbacks.

**$http** is a service. You passed the required data in it's parameter.

```
$http({})
       ^options
```

After calling this $http will do it's work and send a request to the provided url asynchronously. But You don't need to debug that part.

```
$http({options})
    .then(function(data){ 
        // mark 1 breakpoint here
    }, function(data){
        // mark another breakpoint here
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already using jQuery along with Angularjs I would recommend you to use the $.params() function to encode the parameter data.
Your $http would be like

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://someService.site.net/site.aspx',
    data:$.params({action:'someAction', position:'founders'}),
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
})
```

Also I suggest you to use the Angular way of doing things rather than using jQuery. You might even like it ;)

Comment: uhmm.. i wanted to do everything using angular js, but I couldn't find answer to my question such as the angular js of parseJSON

Comment: You could just go with native `JSON.parse()` or the Angular's `Angular.fromJSON()`. Also you could replace `$.params` with Angular's `$httpParamSerializerJQLike` [link](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.1/docs/api/ng/service/$httpParamSerializerJQLike)

Comment: what difference does it make for my code other than being that as the angular way of parsing json to an object?

Comment: Refer [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29243854/difference-between-angular-fromjson-and-scope-eval-when-applied-to-json-string)

Answer (score 1):

**First thing is:** you can simply use your `$http` function like this:

```
var config = {
    headers : {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;'
}};

$http.post('http://someService.site.net/site.aspx',
           {action:'someAction', position:'founders'},
           config)
     .success(function(response) {
        var json =jQuery.parseJSON(response);
        var htmldata="";
        for(i=0; i<json.length; i++) {
            var htmlInfo = '<li><div class=\'col\'><a href="'+ json[i].Id +'"><img width=\'100%\' height=\'auto\' src="'+json[i].Image + '" class=\'profile-img\' /><h3>' +json[i].Name+'</h3><p>'+json[i].Title+'</p></a></div></li>';

            htmldata+= htmlInfo;
        }
        jQuery("#vflist").html($sce.trustAsHtml(htmldata));
     })
     .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          console.log(status);
     });
```

**Secondly**, as you can see in the above code I have used `$sce.trustAsHtml()` -- this is required when you are pushing some html to `DOM` via `$http` - or it will just show the codes with tags. You have to *inject* `$sce` in the controller definition.

Comment: it didn't work.. hmm what else am i missing.. but thanks for the information sir @himel

Comment: hmm it's hard to say - where the error is occurring without the context.

Comment: when I debug the code, it hits at the error, and it shows the config thing Content-Type:"application/x-www-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;"

Comment: my bad - there was a semi colon missing after the config variable declaration. Can you check now pls?

Comment: hmm it didn't change a thing, it doesn't hit in success nor error :( sorry for being so noob -_-

Answer (score 0):

put this line before calling ajax this works for me hope for you to

```
$http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Basic YmVlcDpib29w';
// YmVlcDpib29w you can put any string
```

This is also given in- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: the value i'm gonna write for the authorization is that 'Basic YmVlcDpib29w'; also?